# Why did Pete apologize to Tony Stark?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, dialogue, avengers-infinity-war

In *Avenger's: Infinity War* just before getting erased Peter apologizes to Tony Stark.

> I don't wanna go. I don't wanna go.
>
> Mr. Stark, please...
>
> Please. I don't wanna go.
>
> I don't wanna go.
>
> I'm sorry.

Why? What is he sorry for?

Comment: I assumed he was apologising for stowing away/tagging along, even when Tony told him not to (and tried to send him back down to Earth to keep him safe). Obviously *we* know that wouldn't have made a difference, but he doesn't know that. I don't know if there's any official statements on this, and don't have time to flesh out an answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Peter lost his father at a very young age. At this stage, Tony is a father figure to him. More so because Peter sees much in common with Tony, both being men of science, superheroes and children at heart (agreed Peter is quite literally one). When he starts to fade, his first reaction is panic! That's when Peter starts to say "*I don't wanna go*" over and over. This part is pretty obvious. He is a young kid, way over his head in this battle and now he's dying.

Eventually, he realises that Tony is as helpless as him. He can't do anything to stop this. He can see the desolation and despair in Tony's eyes. It is at this moment that Peter eventually accepts his fate. In his dying moments, he apologises to Tony for failing him. This is a sincere sorry that comes from a son who feels he let his father down.

Tony didn't even want Peter here in the first place. He deployed the spider suit's emergency protocol to get Peter off the spaceship. It was Peter who decided to stay, to help Tony. And now he feels remorse for not listening to him. For he knows, how hard his death will hit Tony. His parting words were both meant as an apology for not doing more as well as for not keeping himself safe.

Comment: Also could this be because.. in spider Man home coming Tony says..after ferry rescuing scene. If someone died today its on you, but if you die it's on me.. now in infinity war Peter is dead and it's on Tony. Could this be the reason

Comment: Exactly! Peter realizes this, albeit a little too late. All he can do now is apologize. If you see my last para and the last sentence, that's one of the 2 reasons.

Answer (score 5):

We can't know exactly, but there are valid (in-character) reasons for Peter to want to apologize to Tony.

### 1

When they were pulling Thanos' glove off, Peter actually succeeded (it slipped off) but Thanos managed to grab it just in time.

This is a possible source for Peter's apology. If only he had been a bit faster in pulling the glove off, Thanos would not have been able to commit his atrocity.

We, the viewer, know that if anyone were to blame, it's Star Lord for losing his cool. However, keep in mind that Peter (Parker) may not have been observing what happened as he was focused on pulling the glove off; or he could just as well regret not having been faster *inspite* of Star Lord's mistake. He was so close to pulling it off, after all.

### 2

Secondly, Peter knows that he went against Tony's wishes by tagging along on the spaceship. Notice Peter and Tony's interaction when Tony finds out he's still on the ship.

> **Tony** You should not be here.
>   **Peter** I was gonna go home.
>   **Tony** I don't wanna hear it.
>   **Peter** But it was such a long way down and I just thought about you on the way...
>   **Tony** And now I gotta hear it.
>   **Peter** ...and kinda stuck to the side of the ship. And this suit is ridiculously intuitive, by the way.
>   **Tony** God damn it.
>   **Peter** So, if anything, ***it's kinda your fault that I'm here***.
>   **Tony** What did you just say?
>   **Peter** ***I take that back***. And now, I'm here in space.
>   **Tony** Yeah, right ***where I didn't want you to be***.

When you look at the scene, you can see that Peter regrets saying that it's Tony's fault *before* Tony responds.

This proves that Peter cares about what Tony thinks, and doesn't want to make Tony feel even more responsible than he already does. And as much as Peter wanted to help, he also acknowledges that Tony isn't happy with Peter's decision because Tony is looking out for him.

This means that he could be apologizing to Tony because he regrets staying on the ship. Not because he's dying, but because he respects Tony so much that he regrets not having listened to him as a matter of principle.

Answer (score 0):

Because of this line that Iron Man had in *Spider-Man: Homecoming*:

> IRON MAN: If you die, I feel like that’s on me.